# Color cell if duplicate value found in another tablesheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have one tablesheet containing all kinds of fruits in column A like:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Apple |  |
| Orange |  |

In another tablesheet I keep recent fruits that are in stock like

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Apple |  |
| Kiki |  |

In this seconds tablesheet I need "Apple" to get color-marked if it also exists in the first sheet.

Countif did not help me with this thus far :(
Thank you!

Comment: Google-Sheets and Excel are different, please only use the relevant tag.

Comment: `COUNTIF()` is exactly what you need in Excel. You may have used it in the wrong way but in general you could just highlight column A in the 2nd sheet, add conditional formatting and use something like `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A;A1)`

Comment: Conditional formatting will do.

Comment: Using `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A;A1)` in Google Sheets' Conditional Formating will return the error "invalid formula", even though it works if entered into a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

in google sheets try:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(Sheet1!A:A); A1)
```

or:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(Sheet1!A:A), A1)
```